# ¡No me funciona el {% load static %} en el html de Django!

Tags: html, python, django, static

No me funciona el **{% load static %}** en mi código, aparece como texto y cuando estoy escribiendo las rutas el intellisense no me sugiere las rutas que tengo en mi carpeta static. He revisado la documentación y tengo todo lo que piden. Así me sale el código:

[image: Así me sale el código]

Aquí adjunto una imagen de cómo tengo mi archivo de settings:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es todo lo que tengo, la verdad estuve viendo en internet y no pude saber qué sucede. Aquí dejo el tutorial que estoy siguiendo y cómo le sale a el (nótese que el load static le sale en otro color y el intellisense le sugiere las rutas existentes en su carpeta):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si es porque utiliza pycharm o a ¿qué más puede deberse esto?

[Video tutorial que estoy siguiendo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqU-RszsDvY&list=PLxm9hnvxnn-j5ZDOgQS63UIBxQytPdCG7&index=17)

Comment: El código de muestra siempre debe ir como texto, por favor revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para más información. Saludos ;)

Comment: Las imagenes no son bien recibidas en el sitio, edita tu pregunta pot favor

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el código debe ir como texto

Answer (score 10):

te falta introducir esta sentencia en la parte superior de tu código HTML:
{% load static %}

[image: Aqui va el codigo]

Despues asegurate que esta es la direccion en donde esta la carpeta static, si se encuentra dentro de otra carpeta, escribe su ruta:

[image: Asi como esta]

Comment: Doy el voto a favir solo por quehas puesto el código en imagen y Juan tambuen tendrá que sufrir copiando el código :]

Comment: Cuanta razón tiene, licenciado @Shiranai

Answer (score -2):

debes cargar

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
```

Comment: Si tenes una nueva pregunta, por favor hacela presionando sobre el botón [Hacer una pregunta](//es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Si tenes suficiente reputación, [puedes votar la pregunta positivamente](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up). Alternativamente, "usa la estrella" para anotartela como favorita y seras notificado de nuevas respuestas.

Comment: Explicanos la causa del problema, la razón de la solución y agrega una demo o método de comprobar la solución.